# If I have a MySQL table with millions of rows, and many rows have the same string in them, should I make a separate table or just use an index?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, indexing

Let's say I have a MySQL `stuff` table with 10 million rows. In one column called `fruit`, the data in that row is 25% filled with the word 'apple', 25% with the word 'orange', 25% with the word 'pear', and the rest are various other words.

The `fruit` column is part of an index.

**From a pure performance perspective** (ignoring how it may save disk space and other resources, and make more logical sense), would changing the `fruit` column into it's own table, and then doing a `JOIN` between the `fruit` and `stuff` table, provide any major performance benefit to any queries?

Or should I just stick to the index?

If this table had multiple rows similar to this (`car`, `toy`, `color`) that had a lot of duplicate data as well, and were also on the index, how would that affect performance?

Comment: there are so many variables here, the only real answer is to try it and see.  or better yet, leave it alone if the existing performance is satisfactory.  using ids can make a more compact index, making it faster to read, especially if the maximum bytes of the character column are long, but joining for every query you do isn't going to be free

Comment: Thank you, I realize my question is a bit vague. I just don't want to break out data into a separate table just for the sake of breaking it out.... I only want to do it if performance can benefit. A major downside of lots of JOIN's is the complexity as well of course.

Comment: again, try it and see.  you might get a slightly better answer if you showed your actual schema (output of show create table) and sample data, queries and explain for those queries.

Comment: I agree — I generally recommend don't try to guess at the right optimization strategy without knowing the _specific_ query or queries you need to run. Every type of optimization improves one query at the expense of other queries. So you really must test a specific case.

Comment: If you ever need to say `WHERE firut = "apple"`, you need an `INDEX` anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Implementing index would still works well even in a very large table. What you should avoid is creating a lot of different indexes in a single table since its going to slow it down considerably.

Found this great article here: https://towardsdatascience.com/indexing-very-large-tables-569811421ee0

> Creating and maintaining an index on a huge table is costlier than on smaller tables. Whenever you create an index, a copy of the indexed column + the primary key is created on disk, and the index is kept in memory as much as possible. If an index has all the data required by a query, it will never go to the actual table. For example, if you have filtered data on customer_id and grouped by year and the index is on (customer_id, year), and you aren’t querying anything else in the SELECT statement, then the query will not go to the disk table to fetch records as the index satisfies all the data requirements for the query.

You should strive to have optimal indexes for all queries, i.e., indexes that cover most, if not all, columns that should use an index in operations like filtering, grouping, sorting, selecting, etc. These indexes are called covering indexes. They cover the requirements for your queries.

Comment: this doesn't seem to address the question as I read it, asking the pros and cons of a fruit character column vs a fruit_id reference to another table

Comment: When you post a quote, you're required to provide a link to the source of that quote for proper attribution. Please edit your question to do so, or delete that content from your post.

Comment: "the index is kept in memory as much as possible" -- No.  It is "cached with [approximately] an LRU algorithm".